# RPM built on same Guest OS, segfaults on another host (Asterisk)

Tags: rpm, asterisk

I have built an RPM for Asterisk 13 for Centos 7 using a build VM running on OSX (MacBook, using Parallels). This is with the intention of using this RPM on both our QA and production systems.

However after installing the RPM on one of the QA servers, asterisk segfaults immediately on startup and does not run. The QA server is another Centos 7 VM running on an Intel CPU with a Centos host using KVM (Qemu).

My RPM spec file is:

```
%define _prefix /usr/local
%define _ver    13.4.0
%define _unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0
%define debug_package %{nil}

Name:          asterisk
Version:       %{_ver}
Release:       1
Summary:       Asterisk
Vendor:        Asterisk
Packager:      Amir Abiri <???>
Source:        http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/asterisk-%{_ver}.tar.gz
URL:           http://www.asterisk.org/
Group:         Applications/Multimedia
BuildRequires: ncurses-devel
BuildRequires: libuuid-devel
BuildRequires: jansson-devel
BuildRequires: sqlite-devel

%description
-

%prep
%setup

%build
./configure
make

%install
make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT
mkdir -p "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/lib/systemd/system"
cp %{_topdir}/PATCHES/asterisk/asterisk.service "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/lib/systemd/system"

%post
/sbin/ldconfig 2>/dev/null
systemctl enable asterisk

%postun
/sbin/ldconfig 2>/dev/null
systemctl disable asterisk

%files
%defattr (-,root,root)
/usr/sbin/*
/usr/lib/asterisk/*
/usr/lib/libasteriskssl.so*
%exclude /usr/include/asterisk*
/usr/lib/systemd/system/asterisk.service
/var/lib/asterisk/*
/usr/share/man/*
```

GCC version is:

```
4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)
```

The build VM (OSX host)'s cpuinfo is:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 70
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
stepping    : 1
cpu MHz     : 2194.000
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm ida arat xsaveopt pln pts dtherm fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 invpcid
bogomips    : 4388.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

The QA server VM's cpuinfo is:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 13
model name  : QEMU Virtual CPU version 1.5.3
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0x1
cpu MHz     : 3092.836
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 4
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 syscall nx lm rep_good nopl pni cx16 hypervisor lahf_lm abm
bogomips    : 6185.67
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

If I run the sagfaulting asterisk through strace, the last half screenful of strace output is:

```
clone(child_stack=0x7f5d487c3f70, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f5d487c49d0, tls=0x7f5d487c4700, child_tidptr=0x7f5d487c49d0) = 4583
mmap(NULL, 507904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f5d486cd000
mprotect(0x7f5d486cd000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7f5d48747f70, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f5d487489d0, tls=0x7f5d48748700, child_tidptr=0x7f5d487489d0) = 4584
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
fcntl(6, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
fcntl(6, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getppid()                               = 4569
read(6, "\242Dm\252\343n\333\22\264\177,\355m\1w\300", 16) = 16
close(6)                                = 0
gettid()                                = 4572
stat("/etc/asterisk/codecs.conf", 0x7fffc4362f20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 507904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f5d48651000
mprotect(0x7f5d48651000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7f5d486cbf70, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f5d486cc9d0, tls=0x7f5d486cc700, child_tidptr=0x7f5d486cc9d0) = 4585
mmap(NULL, 507904, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f5d485d5000
mprotect(0x7f5d485d5000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7f5d4864ff70, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f5d486509d0, tls=0x7f5d48650700, child_tidptr=0x7f5d486509d0) = 4586
brk(0)                                  = 0x1993000
brk(0x19b4000)                          = 0x19b4000
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
fcntl(6, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
fcntl(6, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
getuid()                                = 0
getppid()                               = 4569
read(6, "\251\357\241U\357\267\34G\314@\272\256r\341\210r", 16) = 16
close(6)                                = 0
gettid()                                = 4572
stat("/etc/asterisk/modules.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2768, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/asterisk/modules.conf", O_RDONLY) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2768, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f5d4b6ab000
read(6, "[modules]\nautoload = no\n\n; This "..., 4096) = 2768
read(6, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(6)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f5d4b6ab000, 4096)            = 0
stat("/etc/asterisk/features.conf", 0x7fffc4362ea0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
--- SIGILL {si_signo=SIGILL, si_code=ILL_ILLOPN, si_addr=0x5d5a57} ---
+++ killed by SIGILL (core dumped) +++
```

Comment: One thing you should be doing is to use the `%configure` macro, instead of calling `./configure` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to disable BUILD_NATIVE option if you want to build on one machine and run it on another.

In your %build section try:

```
./configure
make menuselect.makeopts
menuselect/menuselect --disable BUILD_NATIVE menuselect.makeopts
make
```